# Don't send existing cookies, but still accept set cookies

Tags: wininet

I am looking at the Wininet APIs for cookies, and I cannot seem to find a flag for that would avoid sending cookies, but still accept them. I am trying to not send in the HTTP request the cookies currently in the machine, but still let the set cookie from the server response be set (and override any existing cookies).

The [closest flag is `INTERNET_FLAG_NO_COOKIES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but that also does not add cookies to the cookie database:

> **INTERNET_FLAG_NO_COOKIES** 
>  0x00080000
>
> > Does not automatically add cookie
> >     headers to requests, and does not automatically add returned cookies
> >     to the cookie database. This flag can be used by HttpOpenRequest and
> >     InternetOpenUrl (for HTTP requests).

Answer (score 0):

One bad solution I found is to iterate through the cached entries with
`FindFirstUrlCacheEntry`, `FindNextUrlCacheEntry` and delete the entries associated with the URL with `DeleteUrlCacheEntry` every time before the request is sent.

Comment: There are ways to "bump" questions on Stack Overflow, but posting something as an answer soliciting more attention isn't one of them. (With a bit more reputation you can place "bounties" on questions. If you edit questions to improve them they automatically get bumped too. Both of those are great ways to get better answers)